# Social Networks: Is there a way to be informed about questions as soon they're asked?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, meta

Is there a way to be informed about questions as soon they're asked?

For instance:

gwibber (notifications)
facebook, google+ (as new on my wall)
twitter (as tweets)
email (ugh.. all that spam)
rss...
some smartphone app...

Those things will keep answerers closer and answers may come faster.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you hover over any tag on the main site, like say [unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/unity) you have a link to an RSS feed and email subscription.

The [official twitter feed](https://twitter.com/#!/StackUbuntu) also sends out questions on a regular basis. And some guy set up [@askubuntufeed](https://twitter.com/#!/askubuntufeed) that sends out a ton of questions.

[This search](https://plus.google.com/s/askubuntu) on google plus seems to capture the questions shared there.